# Can I load a library or process with limited permissions?

Tags: linux, process, permissions

This is an imaginary example of what I like to do. Don't take it too literally.

Let say my process is being ran as www-data and I have a lua script called thedevil.lua. It will try to delete, corrupt and cause as much problems as possible. I'd like to fire up a process (or load a shared object) that has a lua interpreter and it will try to ruin all my websites as the user is www-data.

Is there a way I can say lets create this process (or load a library) with LIMITED permissions. Say the script is in `/var/www/devilscript/thedevil.lua`. I'd like to give it permissions for `/tmp/www/devilscript` and `/var/www/devilscript/`. Is that possible? I don't want to create a new user called devilscript and give it limited permissions than run the process as that user. I just want to say I am www-data but I only want to give this process/lib a subset of what I can do.

-edit- Could you give me the name of the functions to execute the said so or binary with lower permissions?
-edit2- Can windows do something like I asked?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, depending on the operating system you are running on, there are various sorts of sandboxing methods available in modern Unix systems. It depends a bit on which one you are running. Under Linux there are almost too many -- SELinux, Apparmor, Tomoyo, and others. FreeBSD has a Mandatory Access Control System as well as the Capsicum capabilities system. Mac OS X has a sandboxing system as well.

Most such systems allow you to reduce the privilege that a particular process gets in a fairly granular manner. In general, capability systems are easier to work with than Mandatory Access Control (MAC) systems, but they are less frequently available.

A primitive way of doing this sort of privilege restriction in older Unix systems was "chrooting" a process, that is, running it in a restricted part of the file hierarchy using the chroot system call. Unfortunately, that remains the only truly portable form of privilege reduction available in Unix systems -- you thus encounter it in the configuration systems of many system daemons.

Comment: I'm using C++ but could you give me the name of a c method that does it? shared library wise i only seen dlopen and it didnt have that option. Process wise i haven't looked yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, it depends both on which precise OS and version of that OS you are using, and even then, the methods involved get unpleasantly complicated. This is going to require the manual I'm afraid. If you can spot your OS in the listing I give above, try looking for manuals for that particular OS -- for example, in Linux, you can check if your system supports SELinux or Apparmor or what have you and consult the manual for it.

Comment: arg. I didnt want to chroot (which i havent done before yet) or create users bc there may be thousands and the project (which is dynamically made) may rename. It be so easy if i could say run this exe as a-virtual-user or me-but-limited. -edit- i'm using debian but i was hoping linux would do this natively.

Comment: If you're using debian, you are probably best off with some code that generates SELinux or Apparmor policies.

Answer (score 1):

SELinux will allow you to create a domain that has restricted access to various file contexts and resources, regardless of the user the process is running as (even root).

Comment: Could i get a bit more information. I'll be reading a script with a path of an so or bin that i need to execute. How do i execute it with the limited permissions. What function do i look up in the man pages?

Comment: It's more than just a function. You need to create a SELinux module in order to do this.

Comment: Only the first time. After that, it's bulletproof.